# React - how to loop and render n elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, for-loop

Currently I'm working on app in which I want to render table with N rows and N columns.

Number of rows and columns will be choosing user.

I'm struggling too long on this and I don't know what to do with it. I've tried several solutions which I've found here on stackoverflow or on Google. But only result I get was Error.

Obviously there have to be two loops. 1st loop is supposed to make tr's and 2nd loop is supposed to made td's and put them inside tr's. I've read somewhere on stackoverflow that you **MUST** use array for it like I'm using. Is there any way to do that without it?

**This is my function**

```
function renderBoard(rows,columns){
    let result=[];
    for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        result.push(<tr></tr>)
        for(var j=0;j<columns;j++){
            result[i] = <td></td>
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Render**

```
return(
        <div>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    {renderBoard(3,3)}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
```

Without 2nd for loop, it was making and rendering three 's .. But when I've tried to fill them with td's ,result is only three td's..

I don't know what to do. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Can you add the sample data you want to render? Your question seems to suggest you already know what you want and that's how you want it. First, for loops are rarely used in rendering data in react. The map function is preferred. Add some sample data to render and we can help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like youre overriding the "tr" tag with the "td" tag every time.
Try to create 2 seperated arrays and combine them afterwards.

```
function renderBoard(intRows, intColumns) {
        var rows = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < intRows; i++) {
            var columns = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < intColumns; j++) {
                columns.push(<td></td>);
            }
            rows.push(<tr>{columns}</tr>);
        }
        return rows;
    }
```

Comment: thank you! Can you please give me some advice for keys inside these two loops? console is throwing me errors because of keys. I've tried to do this.

columns.push(<td key={i}></td>);

and for rows - rows.push(<tr key={j}>{columns}</tr>);..but it throws me another error that 2 elements has same key value

Comment: When you're using the the indexes there will be duplicated keys with the second row of course. You could combine those keys with key={i+"-"+j}

Comment: Is there any fix for it? So there will be no duplicate errors

Comment: Sry, clicked enter too fast ;). I edited my old comment allready.

Answer (score 0):

checkout this code snippet

```
render() {
    return <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                {this.renderColumns()}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {
                this.renderRows()
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}


renderRows = () => { 
    const {rows} = this.props;
    return Array(rows).map((row,index) => <tr key={index}>{this.renderColumns(index)}</tr>)
}

renderColumns = (row) => { 
    const {cols} = this.props;
    return Array(cols).map((col , index) => <td key={index}>{row} - {index}</td>)
}
```

Comment: Ali are you there?

Comment: @Pinncik yeah I'm available

Comment: Can I ask you for advice ?

Comment: yeah sure, go a head

Comment: I have a problem with my tic tac toe. Recently I’ve added feature that allows you to play against computer. Problem is that when you win, computer makes one more move but its not supposed to do that . Its because im checking it asynchronous. So i’ve tried to add useEffect to check it. It goes like this - useEffect(()=>{if(winner !== false){setPlayerVsPlayer({AI:false,AImove:false})}}).. so it is supposed to stop computer move if there is winner but it doesnt.. codesandbox link here - https://codesandbox.io/embed/cold-shape-xg7l7?file=/src/App.js&codemirror=1

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you